# create a continuous query using kafka and flink

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, continuous-query-notification

I'm new to the streaming community
I'm trying to create a continuous query using kafka topics and flink but I haven't found any examples so I can get an idea of how to get started
can you help me with some examples?
thank you.

Comment: You'll find several examples here: https://docs.immerok.cloud/docs/how-to-guides/development/introduction/ (note, I work for immerok).

Comment: This example -- https://docs.immerok.cloud/docs/how-to-guides/development/batch-and-streaming-with-the-apache-flink-table-and-datastream-apis/ -- might be the best place to start.

Comment: You seem to be requesting outside sources (examples). Be advised that per our [on-topic guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), requests for external resources (such as guides/examples and libraries, etc) are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, I'm guessing you want to use kafka as source for continuous data. In this case you can use kafka-source-connector(linked below) and if you want to slice it with time you can use flink's Window Processing Function. This will group your kafka messages streamed in a particular timeframe like a list/map.

[Flink Kafka source connector](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/)

[Flink Window Processing Function](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/)

Comment: yes that's the idea, I'm trying to get sensor data as kafka source, and create a flink table then run continuous query over the table

Comment: @user20740519 you might find this link useful as a starting point

https://github.com/redpanda-data/flink-kafka-examples

Comment: thank you, but this one does not integrate topic data in a flink table

Comment: you might want to use rocksDB as Flink backend for this use case

Comment: i dont want to store the data in a database just a flink dynamic table and to run a query over it continuously thanks